# How can I change the text of a password field from javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, passwords, forms

I have an chrome extension in which I want to automatically fill in a username and password field with information the user has entered already (into my application) by running external javascript on the page. I figured out how to fill in the username, but I can't figure out how to automatically check a checkbox or fill in the password.

Comment: you should let the browser handle the saving of usernames/passwords

Comment: Nothing like sending a password in clear text to really beef up security. This also implies you're storing it in clear text. Oh dear.

Comment: I didn't really think about that. Maybe I should just have them enter it every time.

Comment: @MikeRobinson FWIW, I updated this to store the passwords encryptedly after finding that I was storing them in plaintext in a file on the hard drive. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without jQuery, one can do as follows:

```
document.getElementById( "password" ).value = "Value";
document.getElementById( "checkbox" ).checked = true;
```

of course replacing `"password"` with the ID of the password input box, and the same with `"checkbox"`.

Comment: Do the checkbox or the password box have an ID?

Comment: nope. they don't. I thought they didn't originally, then I realized the username did, so they must too, but then I went back over the HTML and saw they don't. oops.

Comment: So then try accessing them in some other way - does the parent have an ID that one can navigate from? Can you post some HTML?

Comment: Meant to say that I was now accessing them through document.forms.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using jQuery you can do this:

```
$('#password').val('whateveryouwant');
$('#checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
```